# Show Loading Image while processing Exec_Shell Script

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need to create a loader div with an image while script.sh is loading

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['restartserver']))
    {
         shell_exec("my-script.sh");         
    }    
?>

<html>
<body>
<div class="refresh">
<form method="post">
    <p>
        <button class="button" name="restartserver">Restart Server</button>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So when i click on the button i need a loading image , when the script.sh is loaded the image-loader disapper and you can click again the button in the div.

Actually when i click on the button the script runs correctly but i see that the browser is loading the script, when finished it reload the same page.

I just want a loder image.gif when the script is loading

I know that this can be done with Ajax but i didn't find a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery for easy ajax.  Following code assumes the restart script outputs "complete" when the reboot is done, and anything else for an error.

```
$('#loaderdiv').html('<img src="loader.gif" />');

$.get('http://path.to/restart.php', function(data){
    if (data == "complete"){
       $('#loaderdiv').html('Reboot Complete');
    } else {
       $('#loaderdiv').html('An Error Has Occured');
    }

});
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <button id="runscript">Run Script</button>
</div>
```

---

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#runscript').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#container').html('<img src="loader.gif" />');

      $.get('http://path.to/execute_sh_script.php', function(data){
            // Code here executes once ajax is complete
            $('#container').html('**strong text**');
      });

  });

});
```

Comment: on button click the system get an .SH script that does not  return any outputs

Comment: If you have no method of returning back a complete or fail on the reboot, then the ajax loader will just spin and spin.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Another question, are you sending the shell_exec to the background?  If so, the server reboot would go on and the page load at the same speed, in which case Im not sure I see the point for an loader gif.

Comment: Actually when i click on the button the script .sh run as well (it's a bash script that modify some data on the server) . The browser detect the finish of the script.. i need a loader.gif when the script is running.. when complete return the button again

Comment: No the shell_exec is not running in background ..that's why the browser detect when it's finished

Comment: how can i insert in the script.sh the variable "Complete" ?

Comment: Gotcha, so yes AJAX is how you would want to do this.  Click button to tigger JS/jQuery to set the loading gif where the button was, then execute ajax call to execute the script.  Once the ajax is complete(when the sh script finishes) then set the button back to a button.  My original response still applies, though I'd nest it into something else.  Will update.

Comment: No luck with this solution.. i've put the shell_exec in a .php script

Comment: Did you reference jQuery in your header? Best the jquey code in a script tag? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: The script.sh is very too long to write down here.. it's just an .sh script that works well in my example code below.. i just need an ajax request instead of the browser loading... maybe without passing the information of the .sh in a php script.. just load the ajax with the example code provided

Comment: Sorry, meant the code for the page that would include the jquery stuff.  HEAD tag codes, SCRIPT references, etc.

jQuery needs to be referenced to function.  jQuery, itself, is a javascript file.  If not referenced then other javascript can't use it's functions.

Comment: The reference I'm referring to: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://path.to/jquery.js"></script>`